# Communicating between ruby and java

Tags: java, ruby

I am currently writing a ruby plugin for a 3d drawing application(written in c ++, ruby is it's scripting language).
What I want to do is communicate between that and another application written in java, both programs are running on the same computer.
The ruby version that is integrated into the 3d drawing application is rather cut down and pretty basic and from what I understand has fairly limited or non existent socket libraries.

Any ideas on how to exchange information  between the two applications would be greatly appreciated.

The amount of information that will be exchanged  will be fairly small.

Comment: Sockets, files, a database ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question may be answered in many, many ways. There is so many possible solutions...

One of the easiest, and yet pretty efficient method which comes to my mind, is to use **[standard input and standard output redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)** to communicate between programs *(written in any language)*.

Your Java program needs to execute a Ruby program, redirecting the input/output streams. I do not know the function which would be used in Java for this task, but in Ruby the method is `IO.popen(command,mode)`.

Your Ruby program, called this way, just reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT` *(plain methods `gets` and `puts` may be used)*.

You haven't said on what system you are programming, so I am not sure whether your platform is able to handle such redirection, or **[names pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)** *(which would be the second easy solution)*.

Comment: Windows and Mac OS.I will be honest, I am pretty much self taught when it comes to programming so my knowledge of shells, pipes etc is basically non-existent.I was thinking of just outputting info to a text file or memory(probably not the correct term), than via the command line letting either ruby or java know that new info has been created and exchange information that way.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but my suggestion is not about command line _parameters_. One program just _starts_ another one, and then they just work together, possibly for a week or longer. Technically my solution is _something like exchanging information through a file_, but you do not need to think about that file's name. Creating a file in the filesystem _might_ be a good idea, but then you should also decide what to do with 'always growing' file - it may finally fill all your disk space. And I like it that you are self-taught ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If not high Performance required ,you can use file on the disk of the computer to change the informations between two applications。
for example,if you want to transfer EVENT1 from Ruby app to Java app:
Ruby app write a flag file called event1.flag on disk dir , while the Java app start a Thead keep searching the dir for .flag file.